# Camera Preview stretched on setDisplayOrientation(90)

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am able to rotate the camera preview from portrait to landscape by using the setDisplayOrientation(90) method but preview won't look realistic and is stretched in landscape mode. I have gone through multiple posts related to the same but not able to succeed with required view. I am trying this on the rooted android Jellybeans version.
Can you please suggest the ways to improve the preview in landscape mode?

below is my code set of CameraPreview and Activity class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    List<Size> sizes;
    Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        setCamera(mCamera);
        try {
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        if (mCamera == camera) { return; }

        mCamera = camera;

        if (mCamera != null) {
            requestLayout();

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            if(mCamera != null){
                //Setting the camera's aspect ratio
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            }

            /*
              Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview surface. Preview must 
              be started before you can take a picture.
              */
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }

    }
    public Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        sizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        if (sizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, width, height);
        }
    }
} 




public class TestCameraActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    protected static final String TAG = null;
    private PictureCallback mPicture;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Context ctx;
    Camera mCamera;
    CameraPreview mPreview;
    Camera.Size optimalSize;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        boolean cameraAvailable = checkCameraHardware(this);

        if(cameraAvailable){
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        }else Toast.makeText(this, "No Camera Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        double aspectRatio =0;
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this,mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
        mPicture = getPictureCallback();

        if(mCamera != null){
            //Setting the camera's aspect ratio
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            optimalSize = mPreview.getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
            aspectRatio = (float)optimalSize.width/optimalSize.height;
        }

     // if(optimalSize!= null){
     //      FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*aspectRatio));
     //      preview.setLayoutParams(params);
     //      LayoutParams surfaceParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*aspectRatio));
     //      mPreview.setLayoutParams(surfaceParams);

     // }
           mPreview.setCamera(mCamera);  
        Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }
        });


    }
    private PictureCallback getPictureCallback() {
        PictureCallback picture = new PictureCallback() {

            @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: " );
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    return picture;};


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
    }

    private void releaseCamera(){
        if (mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }


    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");

        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    /** Check if this device has a camera */
    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            // this device has a camera
            return true;`enter code here`
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value that you pass to `setDisplayOrientation` is not fixed: it's dependent on the individual [camera's orientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#orientation) (where the "top" of the camera is) as well as the current orientation of the device itself. By setting it to a constant value, your preview may look correct in one orientation but in another will be as you described.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)) provides the math that you need to take both into account when setting this value:

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
    int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
        new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

Comment: Implemented the serCameraDisplayOrientation but no improvement in the aspect ration, still the preview is streched, can you suggest please